# Does anyone know how to get Edittext value in service?

Tags: android, service

I want to access `EditText` value in service but I don't no exact way of doing that. I have done this code.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext; 
Edittext et = (EditText)context.findViewById;
```

But it doesn't give me `findViewById` method.

Can anyone give me some hint that how can I access EditText value in service.

Comment: check my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817775/does-anyone-know-how-to-get-edittext-value-in-service/30817796#30817796

Comment: can you explain why you need to access shared ET using services ?

Comment: Nader I am trying to achieve some new things in android. It's easy to access EditText in Activity that is in foreground but i want to check that how we can access in service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Code may help you to get Edittext in Service

```
context = getApplicationContext();
Activity a=(Activity)context;
EditText editText = (EditText)a.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: What should I pass in the Intent in my `MainActivity`, I am getting an error 
> android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: You should pass MainActiviy.this or else this only

Comment: I've tried `getApplicationContext` `getBaseContext` `MainActivity.this` `this`, but nothing worked. 

Answer (score 1):

> first u need to bind the service,
>
> > in activity,you can get the service reference in the service
> >     connection. and pass EditText reference to service. and then set the
> >     text to it(check reff of edittext is null or not).

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` is the method of the **View** class and you can't call it on **Context** object especially on Application context. So you need to call `findViewById()` on the View which contains your EditText. Then to get entered value you could call `getText()` on your EditText and put this value as a StringExtra to your Intent if you're using IntentService for example