# service cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-context

I am trying to access a editText and a Button in a Service.
I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546802/6890234) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817894/6890234), and tried to merge and work out, but no gain. What am I missing here? I have seen other similar answers too and been trying to get it done from last 2 days but all in vain. Any other way of accomplishing it will also be welcome.

Here is the relevant code: 
**`MainActivity.java`**

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
            }
        });
```

**`MyService.java`**

```
        Context context = MyService.this;
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        Button stopButton = activity.findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        EditText editTextUsername = activity.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
```

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
```

But I get this error: 
**LOGCAT**

> 11-14 02:55:07.835 5906-5906/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.nwagh.myapplication, PID: 5906
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   com.example.nwagh.myapplication.MyService@32189af with Intent {
>   cmp=com.example.nwagh.myapplication/.MyService }:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.nwagh.myapplication.MyService cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3060)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:153)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.nwagh.myapplication.MyService cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity
>                                                        at com.example.nwagh.myapplication.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:68)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3043)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)  11-14
>   02:55:07.844 5906-5906/? E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get
>   MQSService.

[Here](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/User-Recognition) is the complete code if you need any more reference.

Comment: So what part of this : `Context context = MyService.this;
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;` doesn't make sense? You are casting `Activity` to a `context` object, which you just assigned as your `Service` instance? Also you are trying to access Activity/UI elements in a Service - this is bound to cause more issues.

Comment: So what should I do? I can't cast a service to a activity.

Comment: You should bind your service to your activity. Then inside service, create a method that takes your activity. This way you can use fields and methods of the activity inside the service

Comment: No they are different Object types, both extend from `Context`, but are not compatible, hence `ClassCastException` - read the docs for `Service` and `Activity`

Comment: But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817775/does-anyone-know-how-to-get-edittext-value-in-service/30817894#30817894) he said it could be done. And it was accepted too.

Comment: what is the purpose of the Service? You should use a service to do long mid/long running background tasks.  You can bind to a service (bound service) or use a started service, what you are trying to do here.  However not too sure of your use case here.

Comment: I am getting values from the sensors and storing them in files, this task is done in the service. I thought it would be a good idea to stop the `MyService` when user clicks on `stopButton`

Comment: @MarkKeen nice to help from the comments.

Comment: @trocchietto not really sure what you mean?

Comment: that is nice you help the community even without writing an answer that would give you reputation points:) respect. In the end the maximum advantage we have replying in stackoverflow is that we learn a lot and become ourselves better devs:) and problem solvers

Comment: @trocchietto Oh right, well sometimes suggesting people have a look at the documentation is the best answer - and more comprehensive than any answer, especially as the OP seems misguided as to the purpose of a `Service` over an `Activity`

Comment: eh eh for sure we went trough the same troubles x years ago:) components, components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are barking up the wrong tree ;-) Your `Service` shouldn't know anything about your UI, nor should it want to muck around with it. If you want to change the UI from your `Service` then you need to delegate that task to the `Activity`. `Activity` is responsible for the UI. There are several well documented approaches you can use:

- `Activity` binds to `Service` and `Service` executes a callback on the `Activity`
- `Service` sends a broadcast `Intent` and `Activity` registers a listener that reacts to the `Intent` when it is broadcast
- Use an Event Bus implementation

Answer (score 1):

Services are NOT activities. Services have no UI related to them.

So:

1) you can't cast a service to an activity.
2) there is no UI for your to find in your service.

Why would a service need a button? services run in the background, with no user interaction.

I don't know what you are doing, but in Android it works like this:

1) activity launches a service (like your button press)
2) service carries out a task in the background
3) service reports back to the activity or terminates

Comment: I want to stop the service when user clicks on the stop Button. How would I know when to call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: Although your answer is nice explains why I can't do what I was trying to do.

Comment: @NikhilWagh - Chris Merrick is right in what he has said, but you are starting to ask questions out of the scope of the original post, I reiterate, read the documentation for a `Service` - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html (it is worth the read!) and the Java exception tells you why you can't do what you are attempting - the accepted answer you pointed to is simply wrong.

Comment: Shall we flag that answer then @MarkKeen